# How to share third party packages during runtime in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, performance, resources, runtime

I have a container app with 4 different Vue apps. They all are using almost same third party packages. I want to share the packages in runtime (i.e., to cache them somewhere), so that any of my apps can use the packages without multiple time downloading and use them from that cache. Basically how can I share dependencies across multiple Vue apps in runtime?

I tried on it but I don't want to use MonoRepo, as that is more to do with build time reduction. I want to share the dependencies in runtime, as whenever an app runs do not have to download them several times

Comment: Module federation or CDN builds in case they exist for the libs in use.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, not sure. But my requirement is something like I have four Vue apps inside one host app. Now, they all use almost same dependencies. I don't want to make all of them download the packages multiple time. If my App1 loads in L1 time, then I want whoever loads in L2 time can use the dependencies from a cached place. Then the app loads in L3 time can also use it. Will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This is what the previous comment addresses.

Comment: As the project uses webpack version 4, module federation will not be possible I believe. Any alternate idea @EstusFlask?

Comment: CDN builds. Also https://github.com/module-federation/webpack-4 , didn't test it

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask I am trying to use module federation with the existing under the hood webpack vue has. It is giving me an error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ModuleFederationPlugin' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ModuleFederationPlugin' of undefined
and in vue.config,js I added something like:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;
Any idea on this?

Comment: But you mentioned above that you use webpack 4. It has no built-in plugin and no `container` too

Comment: Yeah but @EstusFlask I am using Vue 3. So it has a webpack inbuilt right? So do you have any idea if it's webpack v4 or v5?

Comment: Vue is browser UI framework, it's irrelevant to build process. The thing that matters is Vue CLI, in case you're using one (you didn't mention this). Vue CLI 4 uses Webpack 4, and 5 uses Webpack 5. Only you can see which versions you use. Considering that it was your comment that "As the project uses webpack version 4", I suppose it was based on something.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask I have updated all the versions and using Module Federation now. So my two apps running in port 9000 and 9004 respectively. I want to share my 9000's dependencies to 9004 app. Running them independently and they have no link as of now, Is this a right way?

Comment: configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin ({
        name: 'methodEditor',
        filename: 'main.ts',
        remotes: {
          methodConfig: 'methodConfig@http://localhost:9004/#/standalone',
        },
        exposes: {},
        shared: {
          vue: {eager: true},
          'vue-router': {eager: true},
          'vuex': {eager: true},
          'vuex-composition-helpers': {eager: true},
          'tiny-emitter': {eager: true},
          'lodash': {eager: true},

Comment: Sharing to here
 configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin ({
        name: 'methodConfig',
        filename: 'main.ts',
        exposes: {},
        shared: {
          vue: {eager: true},
          'vue-router': {eager: true},
          'vuex': {eager: true},
          'vuex-composition-helpers': {eager: true},
          'tiny-emitter': {eager: true},
          'lodash': {eager: true},
          'element-plus': {eager: true},
          'axios': {eager: true},
          'core-js': {eager: true},

Comment: Seems to be ok. I didn't use W4 plugin myself. If there's a problem with it, consider reasking a question with current implementation, it should help

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask for helping every time. I am gonna re ask the question with proper errors

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, working with Module Federation nowadays. Can you please let me know if we can make a top-level container in Vue with all the dependencies loaded and then it get consumed by the host?
Like: remotes -> Container (containing third parties ) -> Host